# Higienizar endereço de email

Tags: php, email, sanitize

Assumindo o seguinte endereço de email:

```
$email = "zuúl@ so.pt";
```

Tentei proceder à higienização do mesmo fazendo uso de:

```
filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); // zul@so.pt
```

Tentei também:

```
preg_replace('/[[:punct:]]/', '', $email); // zuúl sopt
```

A ideia é que pelo fato do utilizador digitar um acento ou um espaço em branco por engano não seja forçado a voltar "atrás" para retificar o endereço pois este tipo de cenários pode ser controlado pela aplicação tirando o trabalho ao utilizador.

## Pergunta

Como higienizar o endereço de email `zuúl@ so.pt` para que fique `zuul@so.pt` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para higienizar endereços de email você pode utilizar as funções `preg_replace` e `iconv`:

```
$email = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9+_.@-]/i', '', iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $email));
```

É importante que você assegure que os caracteres de entrada estejam na codificação esperada, seja em tempo de execução com `setlocale` ou através de variáveis de ambiente (ex.: [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_env.html)):

Comment: Parece-me que ele também esta a falar de caracteres especiais, e não apenas de espaços

Comment: @CesarMiguel falha de atenção minha... já corrigi a resposta :)

Comment: Uma entrada de `#zuúl@ so.pt` resulta em: `zuul@so.pt` utilizando `setlocale(LC_ALL,'pt_PT.utf8')`. Impecável.

Answer (score 0):

Com recurso à função [`iconv`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> que nos permite fazer a conversão de uma *string* para um *charset* especifico:

```
iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', "zuúl@ so.pt"); // zu?l@ so.pt
```

Agora, é preciso indicar qual o [locale](http://php.net/manual/en/class.locale.php) <sup>(Inglês)</sup> onde a lingua deve ser recolhida para que os caracteres acentuados não resultem em `?`:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,'pt_PT.utf8');
iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', "zuúl@ so.pt"); // zuul@ so.pt
```

Por último, aplica-se isto à [primeira resposta do @Willy Stadnick](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/37595/1) para remover também os espaços:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL,'pt_PT.utf8');
preg_replace('/\s/', '', iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', "zuúl@ so.pt"));  // zuul@so.pt
```

**Nota:** A solução nesta resposta lida apenas com espaços e acentuação. Caracteres especiais não são removidos.